# Python: Flask server on Windows -- how to SSL ify the Flask web server?

Tags: python, ssl, flask

I have an ssl cert imported into the personal store in the computer account.

I thought this would do it:

```
netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:443 certhash=8caef2be185a0c94d################ appid="{7E46BD40-39C6-4813-B414-019AD3332421}"   
netsh http add iplisten ipaddress=0.0.0.0:443
```

But it is serving plain text, not over SSL.

What step is missing?

Comment: What's your python code in which you create the flask server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways we found:

a) Modify the python sources of the app to reference an ssl cert that you keep locally on the file system

or

b) Use IIS as reverse proxy, which is rather fast to set up. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50610437/147637