# How can a Flask web server on Windows use an SSL Certificate from the Windows certificate store?

Tags: python, ssl, flask

Most SSL examples for Flask require that the private key be on the file system. We find that insecure.

How can Flask load the SSL certificate from the Windows certificate store?

Comment: Windows certificate store stores the private key locally: %SystemRoot%\System32\Certlog (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb540795(v=vs.85).aspx). Have you tried just setting the ssl_context to the absolute path to that file?

Comment: Alternatively, would it be acceptable to use IIS (or whatever server) as a reverse proxy and offload SSL from your application entirely?

Comment: @sytech Using IIS in that way is a funny idea. Not what I want to do (what a mess!) but it would work.

Comment: This is how I deploy the vast majority of my Flask and Django applications; or using wfastcgi/mod_wsgi. It's ideal (IMO) to have the webserver handle authentication. IIS/Apache will support just about any auth method you can think of and its modules will be well-maintained and supported. Most of my apps integrate with an identity service (e.g. Shibboleth) -- Support for shibboleth on IIS/Apache is easy; support & maintenance built into a language-specific framework is not as easy to come by.

Comment: @sytech You win. I set up IIS as reverse proxy, terminating SSL on IIS. Easy to set up, but it is an unwanted layer of complexity. Oh well. Done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We solved by using IIS as a reverse proxy, as doced here:

https://developers.coveo.com/display/public/SearchREST/Configuring+HTTPS+Reverse+Proxy+in+IIS

and here

https://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/creating-a-reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-for-iis